# Зачем может понадобится добавлять первичный ключ с двумя значениями?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Зачем может понадобится добавлять первичный ключ с двумя значениями?

*пример запроса:*

```
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE cities
         ADD CONSTRAINT ex PRIMARY KEY (id, id2)
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Очевидно потому, что только вместе они однозначно идентифицируют хранимую сущность.

Comment: @avp можно пример?

Comment: если не должно быть повторяющихся парных записей по колонкам id,id2.
А вообще лучше это проиндексировать подобным образом с префиксом UNIQU, чем делать первичный ключ составной.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Составные ключи могут быть полезны для таблиц, которые содержат связи между сущностями. Например, у нас есть следующие таблицы: `Студенты`, `Предметы` и `Оценки`.

Таблица `Оценки` связывает студентов с предметами и содержит оценки студентов по предметам: `СтудентИд`, `ПредметИд`, `Оценка`. Казалось бы, очевидным будет сделать суррогатный первичный ключ: `СтудентПредметИд`. Но тогда может возникнуть проблема неконсистентных данных: будет возможно одному студенту поставить две разных оценки по одному и тому же предмету. Например:

СтудентПредметИд  СтудентИд  ПредметИд  Оценка

1                                   1                    1                    3

2                                   1                    1                    5

В этом случае пригодится составной ключ `(СтудентИд, ПредметИд)`, которого будет достаточно для идентификации записи.

Comment: Это вы рассказали про уникальные ключи. Первичный ключ будет иметь отличия и побочные эффекты. В частности: первичный ключ будет кластерным и при добавлении записи по студенту 1 строки будут физически переупорядочены в соответствии со значениями индекса; значения из кластерного индекса будут добавлены в данные других индексов как адреса записей, таким образом увеличивая размер этих других индексов.

Answer (score 1):

Например классический случай: организация связи многие-ко-многим. Вот как на Stack Overflow есть таблица Posts, есть Tags и связь между ними

```
CREATE TABLE PostTags (
  PostId      INT NOT NULL,
  TagId       INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(PostId, TagId),
  KEY(TagId, PostId)
)
```

Еще один показательный случай: история изменений чего-либо. Надо ссылаться на ID записи в таблице, которая изменяется и на время изменения. Эта пара значений очевидно уникальна, поэтому логично объявить её первичным ключём.

```
CREATE TABLE SubjHistory (
  SubjId      INT NOT NULL,
  Modified    DATETIME NOT NULL,
  UserId      INT NOT NULL,
  Changes     BLOB,
  PRIMARY KEY(SubjId, Modified),
  KEY(UserId, SubjId)
)
```

Comment: "Многие ко многим" находящиеся в одной таблице по другому называются. И подобных связей надо избегать как минимум и уж точно не первичный ключ.

Comment: @IvanZakirov, не понял Вас, если честно. В какой это "одной таблице" и почему нельзя PK ? Расскажите это не мне, но авторам этого сервиса, структура от них :)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего этого требует логика организации таблиц в базе данных. Обе колонки являются "определяющими" для строки в таблице.

Например, у вас есть кросс-таблица `Table1Table2Link` для организации связи многие-ко-многим между `Table1` и `Table2`. Логично в такой таблице определить составной первичный ключ из идентификаторов `table1Id` и `table2Id`.

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант: в одну таблицу сгружаем данные из многих таблиц источников одинаковой структуры. Тогда в ней PK будет: PK источника + ID идентифицирующий сам источник.

Answer (score 0):

Пример: серия  и номер паспорта. Номер паспорта в пределах своей серии должна быть уникальной.